# Make Div "catch" top of page when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a header on a website that is `fixed 20px` from the top of the page.

However, I want this to catch the top of the page when scrolling and become fixed to the top of the screen once the user has scrolled that 20px down.

CSS

```
#header{
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    background: url(../images/header-fill2.jpg) repeat-x top;
    position: fixed;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 20px;
    z-index: 5000;
}
```

I imagine some form of JavaScript is required but have little to no JavaScript experience, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please post a JSFiddle of what you currently have so people can work off of that.

Comment: In the future, we can use `position: sticky` (http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit). However, support right now is pretty low (http://caniuse.com/css-sticky).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `scroll` event tells you when the window scrolls. Then, use the `scrollTop` to find out how much closer to `0` to go:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  $("#header").css("top", Math.max(0, 20 - $(window).scrollTop()));
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/wequr/1)

Or to avoid constantly re-creating objects:

```
(function() {
  var $wnd = $(window),
      $header = $("#header");
  $wnd.on("scroll", function() {
    $header.css("top", Math.max(0, 20 - $wnd.scrollTop()));
  });
})();
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/wequr/2)

Comment: Cheers T.J. Switched over to your version now. Appreciate the help. Andy

Comment: @AndyKing: Glad that helped. You are, of course, free to change your accepted answer. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Just listen for the `scroll` event and read the value of `$(window).scrollTop()` and set the `top` according to that.
Something like:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('#header').css('top', $(window).scrollTop() > 20 ? '0px' : '20px');
});
```

[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/VmjeF/)

Comment: this worked perfectly. Thank you very much and sorry for the Java / Javascript!

Comment: @AndyKing: If you change the main line in the middle to `$('#header').css('top', Math.max(0, 20 - $(window).scrollTop()));`, it'll be smooth rather than snapping to the top suddenly. ([Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VmjeF/1/)) You might also want to avoid constantly re-creating those objects, scrolling happens a **lot**.

Answer (score 0):

Thats how I do that with jQuery.
The position is also cached, for performance reasons:

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/StephanWagner/u3yrS/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var cfixed_nav = false, wscroll;

    var setScroll = function() {
        wscroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        var fixed_nav = wscroll > 20; // Set pixel amount here

        if (fixed_nav != cfixed_nav) {
            $('body')[fixed_nav ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('fixed');
            cfixed_nav = fixed_nav;
        }
    };

    setScroll();
    $(document).scroll(setScroll);
});
```

With CSS you set the fixed position:

```
.fixed #header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%
}
```

Also remember, that when the header gets the fixed position, those 20px of the header are missing. So you can add a body padding for example:

```
.fixed {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Or you add an element with 20 Pixel height and swap display none / block depending on the .fixed class in the body